# Speech Recognition in Call : Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, phone-call, obscured-view

I have a below requirement in Windows Phone 8 to run voice listener in background agent whenever an incoming call comes or for an outgoing call. The voice listener should stop when there was NO call.

Eg: When I lift an incoming call and while speaking. I would like to say a voice command say "SPEAKER", then the speaker should ON

I saw obscured events can be used for detecting calls. But am unable to start the voice listener from background agent. Kindly please assist.

Here is the method I am using in the ScheduledAgent.cs file, but no luck

```
private async void SpeakTest()
{
    SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognizerUI();

    SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await speechRecognition.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
     if (recoResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
     {
         lblMessage.Text = recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, You can not run a background task whenever you want. OS will decide when to run your task agent. It'll not run continuously. Rather it'll run in interval 
**Second**, In windows phone 8 ( not elsewhere) the microphone is muted to external app. 
**Third**, You shouldn't try to run `SpeechRecognizerUI` from background agent.